# $A$ and $B$ are ideals of a ring ${R}$ such that $A\cap B=\{0\}$. Prove that $st=0$ for every $s\in A, t\in B$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

$A$ and $B$ are ideals of a ring ${R}$ such that $A\cap B=\{0\}$. Prove that $st=0$ for every $s\in A, t\in B$.

I have no idea how to solve it. please help.

Comment: Is your ring commutative? are $A$ and $B$ two-side ideals?

Comment: @Xammm nothing more mentioned

Comment: @user1942348 given $s\in A$ and $t\in B$, $st\in A$ (since $A$ is an ideal) and $st\in B$ (since $B$ is an ideal). Now you can use the condition $A\cap B = \{0\}$ to deduce $st = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

I think that $A$ and $B$ must be two-side ideals. In that case it's true that $AB\subseteq A\cap B$, so since $st\in AB$, then $st\in A\cap B=\{0\}$, then $st=0$, for every $s\in A$ and $t\in B$.

Comment: Take $A$ to be a right ideal and $B$ a left ideal;Isn't the result true then?

Comment: @learnmore please elaborate what you actually want to mean

Comment: @learnmore it's true, but it's false if $A$ is a left ideal and $B$ is a right ideal.

Comment: @user1942348 Do you know what [left and right ideals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_(ring_theory)#Definitions) are?

Comment: @Wojowu yes. I know the defn

Comment: @Xammm You proceeded as most textbooks in algebra do: imposing extra conditions and proving the result. Much more instructive (and often difficult) is to give counterexamples. This would definitely show what and why you need in order to get the desired result.

Comment: @user26857 I suppose that I did that because I study algebra using textbooks xd, but sure you're right, it's more difficult to give counterexamples. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: For a counter example I suggest the following two left ideals in $M_2(\mathbb C)$: $I$ is the set of matrices having the first column zero, and $J$ the second column zero. Then $I\cap J=(0)$, but we get $s\in I$ and $t\in J$ such that $st\ne0$. (A similar counterexample can be provided for $I,J$ both right ideals. It remains to give one for $I$ left ideal, and $J$ right ideal.)